# Sudo, Virtualbox, and Permission issues. (The Good, The Bad, The Ugly)

Tags: permissions, virtualbox, sudo, vagrant

I'm testing a development image of Linux Mint built by myself and a friend. I'm testing it out by trying to do all the normal things that you would do in a web development workflow (Install an editor, bring up vagrant boxes, etc). While doing this I ran into an interesting permissions issue. When I tried to sudo anything in my `$HOME` directory I was met with a permission denied. for example

```
sudo vim ~/bad.txt
```

was met with:

```
~/bad.txt" [Permission Denied]
```

So as a test I created a folder in my `~/` directory and `chmod 777` it and everything worked in there. So I proceeded to install Vagrant and VirtualBox and noting seemed to go wrong until I ran vagrant up for a plain scotchbox. Where I received the following error

```
There was an error while executing `VBoxManage`, a CLI used by Vagrant for controlling VirtualBox. The command and stderr is shown below.

Command: ["import", "/public/home/username/.vagrant.d/boxes/scotch-VAGRANTSLASH-box/2.5/virtualbox/box.ovf", "--vsys", "0", "--vmname", "scotch-box_default_1446564755217_55786_1449843924304_26032", "--vsys", "0", "--unit", "7", "--disk", "/username/VirtualBox/Machines/scotch-box_default_1446564755217_55786_1449843924304_26032/box-disk1.vmdk"]

Stderr: 0%...10%...20%...30%...40%...50%...60%...70%...80%...90%...100%
Interpreting /public/home/username/.vagrant.d/boxes/scotch-VAGRANTSLASH-box/2.5/virtualbox/box.ovf...
OK.
0%...
Progress state: VBOX_E_IPRT_ERROR
VBoxManage: error: Appliance import failed
VBoxManage: error: Could not create the directory '/username/VirtualBox/Machines/scotch-box_default_1446564755217_55786_1449843924304_26032' (VERR_ACCESS_DENIED)
VBoxManage: error: Details: code VBOX_E_IPRT_ERROR (0x80bb0005), component Appliance, interface IAppliance
VBoxManage: error: Context: "int handleImportAppliance(HandlerArg*)" at line 779 of file VBoxManageAppliance.cpp
```

As you can see it's trying to read a folder named my username in the / directory. So it seems that not only permissions are messed up but something with the path to home is also messed up. So what we would like a little help with is understanding where we screwed up and how we can go about fixing it.

I've looked for similar issues so I've checked

```
sudo su - 
id
```

and the UID is indeed 0. I really want to understand where we screwed up here so we can avoid the same mix ups in the future. Thanks.

Comment: what are the permissions on `~/bad.txt`?  `.txt` is an odd extension for an executable...

Comment: Does the directory creation fail because it's not a child of an existing directory, or is there perhaps an SELinux issue in play?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32862/discussion-between-mc0e-and-chris-maness).

Comment: For anyone else reading:  after a bit of chatting, it emerged that /public/home/username is mounted from an NFS server.  There's more to figure out, but I think that's probably where the issues arise.